# Is there a way to view notification history?

Tags: software-recommendation, notification, notify-osd

If I walk away from my PC, then there is a good chance I might miss certain notifications. I've seen in KDE that notifications get stored and stacked until you click them (or whatever).

Unless I'm missing something, Ubuntu doesn't seem to have a history of clickable notifications.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This is almost 5 years old. Any idea if there're newer solution?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take [Recent Notifications](https://launchpad.net/~jconti/+archive/recent-notifications).

[image: screenshot recent notifications]

In a terminal run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/recent-notifications
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-notifications
```

Alternatively you could download the package directly on the [launchpad-site](https://launchpad.net/~jconti/+archive/recent-notifications/+packages). For Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric on an i386-machine choose [`indicator-notifications_0.1.4-2~ppa~oneiric_i386.deb`](https://launchpad.net/~jconti/+archive/recent-notifications/+files/indicator-notifications_0.1.4-2~ppa~oneiric_i386.deb). (Don't install `recent-notifications`)

After installing run <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> `unity --replace`.

You will find a little mailbox in the panel:

[image: recent notifications in panel]

It is possible to align the icon to your desktop theme, i. e. when you use Faenza:

```
mkdir ~/.icons/Faenza/status/scalable
cp /usr/share/icons/Faenza/status/scalable/user-available-symbolic.svg ~/.icons/Faenza/status/scalable/indicator-notification-unread.svg
cp /usr/share/icons/Faenza/status/scalable/user-away-symbolic.svg ~/.icons/Faenza/status/scalable/indicator-notification-read.svg
```

[image: new Faenza icons]

To stop it you need to unistall it:

```
sudo apt-get purge indicator-notifications
```

Then again run <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> `unity --replace`.

To remove the ppa run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:jconti/recent-notifications
```

Comment: Can this be done without adding another PPA? I think a lot of us avoid doing this wherever possible.

Comment: I did as you said "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/recent-notifications
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-notifications" then "unity --replace", all commands seemed succesful output, but there is no mailbox icon in the panel. I have had notifications and it's stil not at all appearing.

Comment: EDIT: Actually, this might not work because I'm not using Unity at all! Three years ago Ubuntu started using Gnome own desktop. So I'll try to find something analogous for gnome.

Comment: The most recent release (here in 2023) of `recent-notifications` is for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

Answer (score 26):

The comment linked here, [Is there a way to view notification history?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105566/is-there-a-way-to-view-notification-history#comment122458_105573), asked:

> Can this be done without adding another PPA?

**Yes**

---

Open two terminal windows (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). The extra window is needed only for test purposes.

---

**Monitor notifications** in one of the terminal windows with:

```
dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'"    |     \
grep --line-buffered  "member=Notify\|string"
```

(to stop it, close the window or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)

**Note** that running this script only shows those notifications occurring from the time it is started and must be run prior to the processes and aps. for which the history is desired. If the terminal window has an insufficient scrollback size either change the scrollback lines in <kbd>**Edit**</kbd> **>** <kbd>**Profile Preferences**</kbd> **>** <kbd>**Scrolling**</kbd> or record the history as described next.

To record the output in a permanent log just redirect it to a file by adding 
`>>path/filename.ext` to the end of the `grep` line. To record and  view the notices
append  `| tee >>path/filename.ext` to the `grep` line.

---

Test it.

1. Using Pangolin 12.04 Live SD/USB
2. Turn wireless networking off & on.
3. Use the other terminal window to make some other notifications with:

```
    for i in {0..100..20};
         do
               killall notify-osd;
               notify-send "testing $i" $i;
               sleep 0.5;
         done
```

---

Results

Judicious use of `grep` and `sed` etc. can  pretty print 
the notifications that are crudely shown below for these monitored examples.
The text that matches the graffiti in the notification pop-up bubbles is shown in **`bold`**. The two strings preceding those are the ap. making the graffiti (ie. "NetworkManager" or "notify-send") and the name of the icon, if any, (ie. "notification-network-wireless-disconnected") to show in the pop-up bubble.

```
   string ":1.380"
method call sender=:1.14 -> dest=:1.379 serial=8691
                path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications;
                         interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
   string "NetworkManager"
   string "notification-network-wireless-disconnected"
   string "MissingLink"
   string "Disconnected - you are now offline"
         string "urgency"
         string "transient"
method call sender=:1.14 -> dest=:1.379 serial=8782 
                path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications;
                         interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
   string "NetworkManager"
   string "notification-network-wireless-full"
   string "MissingLink"
   string "Connection Established"
         string "urgency"
         string "transient"
method call sender=:1.386 -> dest=:1.389 serial=7 
                path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications;
                         interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
   string "notify-send"
   string ""
   string "testing 0"
   string "0"
         string "urgency"
```

***. . .***

```
    method call sender=:1.426 -> dest=:1.429 serial=7
                path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications;
                         interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
       string "notify-send"
       string ""
       string "testing 80"
       string "80"
             string "urgency"
    method call sender=:1.430 -> dest=:1.433 serial=7
                path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications;
                         interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
       string "notify-send"
       string ""
       string "testing 100"
       string "100"
             string "urgency"
```

cross references:
 ... to be done ...

Comment: Package that baby up and get it into the distro

Answer (score 1):

How to do this in 18.04 and beyond:

Keyboard shortcut: `Cmd-V`

Via the mouse: Click on the clock in the top center of the screen.

The notifications appear in the left half of the pane that pops up.

Comment: The question is how to recover them _after they had been dismissed_ from this piece of UI that you suggest.