# Thunderbird notifications not appearing

Tags: 11.10, thunderbird

For some reason, Thunderbird's new mail notifications are no longer appearing at the top right of my screen. I hear the pop sound of new messages, and Unity's Thunderbird icon receives a red number indicating the number of new messages.

But no Ubuntu notifications at all.

This seems to have happened after my latest series of updates.

Other notifications are working, however.

Comment: Which Thunderbird Addons are installed?

Comment: The easiest way to answer that is with a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/QMHtY.png

Comment: Did you check settings? `Edit → Preferences → General → Show an alert` - maybe it changed for some reason? http://i.stack.imgur.com/elMNo.png

Comment: I did check, yes, and it was checked.

Comment: My guess is that it's a conflict with an extension.

Comment: You could check this by disabling them. According to your image the 2nd, 3rd and 6th addons were original. Did you reboot meanwhile? Maybe it works afterwards. Just send E-Mails to yourself to test ;-) Possibly you could install [`recent-notifications`](http://askubuntu.com/a/105573/46531) to see if the system gets the message itself, and whether its a problem of `notify-osd`. (Don't know if this helps.) Apart from that I don't have an idea what you could do.

Answer (score 0):

There was some package in earlier 10.10 that made mozzila notifications show up in ubuntu. But when I upgraded it was amongst the removed and unsupported ones.

Sadly, I don't remember the name now.

EDIT: Thunderbird identificator is not compatible with thunderbird 10.02