# NotifyOSD history

Tags: notify-osd

Does NotifyOSD keeps a history of its messages? If so how can I access it?

Because sometimes it would be very useful to me being able keep record of the notifications in order to report some bugs and other related stuff.

Comment: Yes it is duplicate, I searched for NotifyOSD and didn't find that Q&A, sorry for that.

Comment: no problem, be happy =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load nautilus from a terminal

```
sudo nautilus
```

so that you can run files and open folders otherwise restricted,

navigate to /var/crash/

There they are. All those pesky crashes. Run each one by clicking (or double clicking) on the file and it opens the error message. Right click and select Open with ... Gedit - Text Editor and view all the details.

Comment: Also add it to your desktop with http://askubuntu.com/questions/105566/is-there-a-way-to-view-notification-history

Comment: Thanks, what I am wanting is exactly what is in the answer you cited in your comment, although not what you said in your answer, in your answer you explain me how to get system crash messages.

Comment: Cool, glad I could point you in the right direction :)