# How to find out which application is sending notifications?

Tags: notification

On Ubuntu 16.04 with Cinnamon installed, I'm seeing advertisement notifications like this one:

[image]

How can I find out which application is sending these notifications so that I can uninstall or disable it?

Comment: Most probably your browser(s). At some point, you may have allowed desktop notifications.

Comment: See https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216
 and chrome://settings/content/notifications

Comment: Assuming Chrome browser let through the dirty deed, go to: `Settings` -> `Privacy and Security` -> `Content settings` -> `Notifications`.  You are presented with a whitelist and blacklist around OS/desktop notifications.  On the whitelist you'll see one of an infinite number of spammy 3rd party content provider that you clicked "Allow" on when prompted.  Remove everything from the whitelist, and if the problem goes away, it was one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do what is being asked, in a general way, i.e. to find out which application is creating a notification, but I found a way to find out which application is creating these particular notifications.

By clicking on them, the default browser (Chrome) opens; as @DK Bose suggested, this implies that it is a browser notification.

Inspecting chrome://settings/content/notifications didn't show any web site that could be creating those notifications, but in this case you should look for other browsers installed in the system.

For instance, Firefox:

[image]

Even though the default browser was opening when clicking on the notification, it was in fact an additional browser that was creating them.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running 16.40. My default browser is Firefox. I found it in settings under privacy -> notifications where it was allowing web-push notifications from certain websites that I must have agreed to have received notifications from, not knowing that they could push them through even though the sites pages aren't loaded. (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox?as=u&utm_source=inproduct).

Answer (score 3):

I am looking a history tool for notification. And see your question here, 
you can find a history from "recent-notification" applet. And a debug command helps you to find more details:

$   dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'"    |     \
    grep --line-buffered  "member=Notify\|string"

Reference:

- https://www.maketecheasier.com/view-past-notification-in-ubuntu/
- [Is there a way to view notification history?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105566/is-there-a-way-to-view-notification-history)

Comment: This is a very old post, but I found this answer a little helpful and then found a much better answer these days using the "Bustle" tool while trying to figure out how to interpret the sender IDs from dbus-monitor output: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69318327/307705